# Taking a programming test and didn't get the pattern algorithmic

Tags: java, algorithm, maps

The question is there is a plane with seat A-K excluding row I. The method gives you the seats that are taken in a String "1C 2B 1J" as an ex.  Find how many families of 4 if they are grouped together or split evenly over an aisle.

Examples:
Given N = 2 and S = "1A 2F 1C", your function should return 2. The following figure shows one
possible way of seating two families in the remaining seats:

Given N = 1 and S = "'" (empty string), your function should return 2, because we can seat at most
two families in a single row of seats,

Given N = 22 and S = "1A 3C 2B 20G 5A", the function should return 41.

So in the

```
 A B C D E F G H J K    A B C D E F G H J K
  XOO    OOXX   XXX     OOX   OOOO   OXO
  XXX    OOOO   XXX     OOX   OOOO   OOO
```

the return should be

```
                        OOX FFFF OXO
                        OXO FFFF OOO
```

should be two because 2 families of four can fit. If the input is (1, "") return 2 for the same reasons shown as to the seating charts given.   I get one more than I should in this algorithm.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.*;
//Available 4seatsections from B-E[1-4] F-J[5-9] with aisles else D-G[3-7]

class AirplaneFamilesNSeatFinder {
static int solution(int N, String S) {
    String[] seats = S.split(" ");
    int numberOfFamilySeats = 0;
    int[][] planeSeats = new int[N][10];
    Map<Integer, Integer> seatsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    
    int[][] takenSeats = new int[N][10];
    seatsMap = validSeats(S, N);
    List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> 
    (seatsMap.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(){
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o2)
        {
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++) {
            for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> seatAssigned : list) {
                int seat = seatAssigned.getKey();
                int row = seatAssigned.getValue();
                if(seat==i && row==k)
                    takenSeats[i][k] = 1;                   
            }
        }
    }
    int seatsNeeded = seats.length*4;
    if(seatsNeeded<(N*10)) {
        for(int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
            for(int k=0;k<10;k++) {
                if((k+1)<10) {
                    k=k+1;
                    boolean foundSeat = false;
                    System.out.println("Debug: " + foundSeat + " " + numberOfFamilySeats + " " + k);
                    if(k==1 && (k+3)<10 && takenSeats[i][k+1]!=1 && takenSeats[i][k+2]!=1 && 
       takenSeats[i][k+3]!=1&& takenSeats[i][k+4]!=1) {
                        foundSeat = true;
                    }else if(k==3 && (k+3)<10 && takenSeats[i][k+1]!=1 && takenSeats[i][k+2]!=1 && 
     takenSeats[i][k+3]!=1&& takenSeats[i][k+4]!=1) {
                        foundSeat = true;
                        takenSeats[i][3]==1
                    }else if(k==5 && (k+3)<10 && takenSeats[i][3]!=1 && takenSeats[i][k+1]!=1 && 
       takenSeats[i][k+2]!=1 && takenSeats[i][k+3]!=1&& takenSeats[i][k+4]!=1) {
                        foundSeat = true;
                    }
                    if(foundSeat) {
                        numberOfFamilySeats++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Debug:foundSeat  " + foundSeat + " " + numberOfFamilySeats + 
       " " + k);
                    foundSeat = false;
                }
            }
        }
        
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    return numberOfFamilySeats;
}

static Map<Integer, Integer> validSeats(String S, int N) {
    String[] seats = S.split(" ");
    int length = seats.length;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Map<Integer, Integer> tempSeatsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    String[] rowNames = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K"};
    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++) {
        for(int k = 0;k<rowNames.length;k++) {
            if(seats[i].contains(rowNames[k])) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(seats[i]);
                Integer seat = 0;
                while (m.find()) {
                  seat =Integer.parseInt(m.group());
                }
                if(seat<=N) {
                    tempSeatsMap.put(seat, k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tempSeatsMap;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1A 2F 1C";
    System.out.println("Number of familes " + solution(3, s));
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code has some bugs and can also be implemented easier:

1. `validSeats` returns for each row `(1,2,...)` only the *last* seat `(A,B,...)` listed in the passed seat list. Therefore some occupied seats are not taken into account. E.g. for the seat list *1C 2B 1G 1E 2F 2D* `validSeats` would only find the seats *1E* and *2D*. This is caused by the use of the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)-type, which can contain each key only once. If a key/value pair (`K1/V2`) is set with [`Map#put`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V)) and a key/value pair (`K1/V1`) with the same key `K1` already exists, the old value `V1` is replaced by the new value `V2`. This means that previously found seats get lost. To prevent this, the `Map`-type must be replaced. One possibility is to fill the later used array `int[][] takenSeats` *directly* instead of taking the detour via the `Map`-instance.

   Also, it's not necessary to split the passed seat list. Instead, the regex mechanism can be applied directly to the passed string.

   A possible implementation would be:

   ```
   private static int[][] validSeats(int numberOfRows, String seatList) {
       int[][] takenSeats = new int[numberOfRows][10]; 
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2}-?[A-Z]");
       Matcher m = p.matcher(seatList);
       while (m.find()) {
           String seat = m.group().replace("-", "");                                   // e.g. 12C
           char letter = seat.substring(seat.length() - 1, seat.length()).charAt(0);   //      12
           String row = seat.substring(0, seat.length() - 1);                          //        C
           int letterIndex = letter > 'H' ? letter - 'A' - 1 : letter - 'A';           // Map ABC DEFG HJK -> 012 3456 789 
           int rowIndex = Integer.parseInt(row) - 1;                                   // Map 123...       -> 012...       
           takenSeats[rowIndex][letterIndex] = 1;
       }
       return takenSeats;
   }
   ```
2. `solution` contains several flaws, e.g.:

   - `int[][] takenSeats` is filled improperly. For the above example with *1E* (as index *04*) and *2D* (as index *13*) only *2E* (as index *14*) is set.
   - An incorrect index is used at several places in the code. E.g. for the case `k = 1` the seats `takenSeats[i][k+1]`, `takenSeats[i][k+2]`, `takenSeats[i][k+3]` and `takenSeats[i][k+4]` are checked. However, since the index is zero-based, the locations `takenSeats[i][k]`, `takenSeats[i][k+1]`, `takenSeats[i][k+2]` and `takenSeats[i][k+3]` would have to be checked.
   - It's not taken into account that within the *same* row the combination *BCDE* excludes the combination *DEFG*. Similarly, the combination *DEFG* excludes the combination *FGHJ*.

   A possible alternative implementation would be:

   ```
   private static int solution(int numberOfRows, String seatList) {
       int numberOfFamilySeats = 0;
       int[][] takenSeats = validSeats(numberOfRows, seatList);                // 0: free, 1: initially occupied, 2: calculated family seats
       for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {           // Check each row
           for (int letterIndex = 1; letterIndex <= 5; letterIndex +=2) {      // Check neighboring seats of B (->CDE), D (->EFG) and F (->GHJ) 
               if (takenSeats[rowIndex][letterIndex] == 0 && takenSeats[rowIndex][letterIndex + 1] == 0 && takenSeats[rowIndex][letterIndex + 2] == 0 && takenSeats[rowIndex][letterIndex + 3] == 0) { 
                   for (int familySeats = 0; familySeats < 4; familySeats++) { // Mark family seats as occupied 
                       takenSeats[rowIndex][letterIndex + familySeats] = 2;
                   }
                   if (letterIndex == 1) letterIndex = 3;                      // BCDE excludes DEFG
                   else if (letterIndex == 3) letterIndex = 5;                 // DEFG excludes FGHJ
                   numberOfFamilySeats++;                                      // Found free family seat
               }
           }
       }
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(takenSeats));                    // Optionally print seat plan
       return numberOfFamilySeats;
   }
   ```

---

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String seatList = "1F 2D 2G 3C 3D 4B 5H 6A 7B 7F";
    System.out.println("Number of families: " + solution(7, seatList)); 
}
```

Output:

```
[[0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Number of families: 6
```

Comment: it's not seeing the matrices.

Comment: I've slightly modified the code so that the content of `takenSeats` is now displayed. Is this what you mean by _matrices_?

Answer (score 0):

this is the same code based on @Topaco solution but in `javascript`

```js
function solution(numberOfRows, seatList) {
    let numberOfFamilySeats = 0;
    const takenSeats = validSeats(numberOfRows, seatList);

    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {
        for (let letterIndex = 1; letterIndex <= 5; letterIndex += 2) {
            if (Array(4).fill().every((_, i) => takenSeats[rowIndex][letterIndex + i] === 0)) {
                Array(4).fill().forEach((_, i) => takenSeats[rowIndex][letterIndex + i] = 2);
                letterIndex += (letterIndex === 1) ? 2 : 4;
                numberOfFamilySeats++;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberOfFamilySeats;
}
```

and here is the `validSeats`

```js
function validSeats(numberOfRows, seatList) {
    const takenSeats = Array.from({ length: numberOfRows }, () => Array(11).fill(0));
    if (seatList) {
        seatList.split(' ').forEach(seat => {
            const [row, column] = seat.match(/(\d+)([A-K])/).slice(1);
            takenSeats[parseInt(row) - 1][column.charCodeAt(0) - 65] = 1;
        });
    }
    return takenSeats;
}
```